# Ayuda con tabla de multiplicar en c++

Tags: c++, array

Necesito crear una tabla de multiplicar con una matriz de tal manera que quede así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no logro hacer que aparezca la tabla del 0, este es mi avance:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
    main()
{
    short A[12][12],f,c;
        for(c=0;c<11;c++)
        {
            A[0][c]=c;    
        }

        for(f=1;f<11;f++)
        {
            A[f][0]=f;
        }

        for(c=1;c<11;c++)
        {
            for(f=1;f<11;f++)
            {
                A[f][c]=A[f][0]*A[0][c];
            }
        }

        for(f=0;f<11;f++)
        {
            for(c=0;c<11;c++)
            {
                cout<<A[f][c]<<"  ";
            }
            cout<<endl<<endl;
        }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

podrían codificarlo por favor?

Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Es bastante sencillo:

```
int tabla[12][12]{};

for (int fila = 0; fila < 12; ++fila)
{
    for (int columna = 0; columna < 12; ++columna)
    {
        tabla[fila][columna] = (fila - 1) * (columna - 1);
    }

    tabla[0][fila] = fila - 1;
    tabla[fila][0] = fila - 1;
}

**tabla = 0;
```

Pero esta solución es muy aburrida, mejor la hacemos genérica con plantillas:

```
template <int NUMEROS>
struct tabla
{
    static constexpr int TAMANYO = NUMEROS + 2;
    int valores[TAMANYO][TAMANYO]{};

    constexpr tabla()
    {
        // Empezamos en 2, no en 0. Ver comentarios.
        for (int fila = 2; fila < TAMANYO; ++fila)
        {
            // Empezamos en 2, no en 0. Ver comentarios.
            for (int columna = 2; columna < TAMANYO; ++columna)
            {
                valores[fila][columna] = (fila - 1) * (columna - 1);
            }

            valores[0][fila] = fila - 1;
            valores[fila][0] = fila - 1;
        }
    }
};
```

Si añadimos un operador de inyección en flujo de datos:

```
template <int NUMEROS>
std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &o, const tabla<NUMEROS> &t)
{
    for (const auto &x : t.valores)
    {
        for (const auto &y : x)
            o << y << '\t';
        o << '\n';
    }

    return o;
}
```

Podemos hacer esto:

```
std::cout << tabla<10>();
```

Que mostrará:

> ```
> 0   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10 
> 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 
> 1   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10 
> 2   0   2   4   6   8  10  12  14  16  18  20 
> 3   0   3   6   9  12  15  18  21  24  27  30 
> 4   0   4   8  12  16  20  24  28  32  36  40 
> 5   0   5  10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50 
> 6   0   6  12  18  24  30  36  42  48  54  60 
> 7   0   7  14  21  28  35  42  49  56  63  70 
> 8   0   8  16  24  32  40  48  56  64  72  80 
> 9   0   9  18  27  36  45  54  63  72  81  90 
> 10  0  10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90 100
> ```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/MRTw3Wou4zgVLYzF).

Comment: No hace falta que comiences los dos bucles desde 0. Si partes de `fila=1` y `columna=1` funciona igual y evitas algunas iteraciones.

Comment: ¡Bien visto @CarlosA.Gómez !

Comment: La verdad que el código que has escrito es buenísimo. Además, al empezar los contadores de los bucles desde 1, como la matriz parte de estar inicializada a 0 al definirla con {}, la línea `**valores = 0;` no te haría falta.

Comment: ¡Brillante @CarlosA.Gómez ! Es más, podemos empezar el bucle en `2` n_n.

Comment: Efectivamente, tienes toda la razón. Más óptimo incluso.

Comment: @CarlosA.Gómez no se puede ser más óptimo que algo. [Óptimo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=R7bbor7) es superlativo ;) podríamos decir que es más eficiente incluso.

Comment: Gracias, no lo sabía.

Answer (score 0):

Fíjate que la tabla que expones tiene dos 0 en ambos encabezados (filas/columnas) mientras que tu código solo saca 1. Tu código más bien debería empezar así:

```
// inicializas la esquina superior izquierda
A[0][0] = 0;
```

Y luego te falta corregir los bucles:

```
// MAL
for(c=0;c<11;c++)
{
    A[0][c]=c;    
}

// Bien
for(c=1;c<12;c++)
{
    A[0][c]=c-1;    
}
```

Fíjate que estoy cambiando tanto el recorrido del bucle como el cálculo del valor asignado. Estás trabajando con una matriz de 12x12, luego el bucle debe iterar desde 1 (porque el 0 es para el encabezado) hasta 11 (incluído). Con el resto de bucles sucede algo similar.

Ahora bien, también puedes optar por no complicarte tanto la vida:

```
A[0][0] = 0;

// Las cabeceras son simétricas
for( int i=0; i<=10; i++)
{
  A[0][i+1] = i;
  A[i+1][0] = i;
}

// Rellenamos la tabla
for( int i=0; i<=10; i++ )
{
  for( int j=0; j<=10; j++)
    A[i+1][j+1] = i*j;
}
```

Y la presentación la puedes mejorar fácilmente con la librería `iomanip`:

```
for(f=0;f<12;f++)
{
  for(c=0;c<12;c++)
  {
    cout<<setw(3)<<A[f][c]<<"  ";
  }
  cout<<endl<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No se si lo que buscas es algo como lo siguiente.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
    main(){
        int T[11][11];
        // fill
        for(int i = 0; i <= 10; i ++){
            for(int j = 0; j<= 10; j ++){
                T[i][j] = i*j;
            }
        }
        //output
        for(int i = 0; i <= 10; i ++){
            for(int j = 0; j<= 10; j ++){
                cout<<T[i][j]<<" ";
            }
            cout<<"\n";
        }
    }
```

Comment: La pega es que los encabezados estan mal... valen todos 0